# WP7 - group of textboxes into some sort of template?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

I'm still pretty new at Silverlight so there might be a way to do this, but I'm just unfamiliar with the terminology...

I basically have this grouping of textboxes and textblocks and I would like to repeat this same grouping whenever the addNew button is clicked.  Is there a way to do this by creating some sort of template?  Or do I have to add each item individually.

```
                <Grid>
                    <toolkit:ListPicker Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Name="listPicker1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}"    FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}" Margin="0,97,167,0"></toolkit:ListPicker>
                    <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,7,0,0" Name="tbDate" Text="Date:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266" />
                    <TextBlock Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,55,0,0" Name="tbItem" Text="Item:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" />
                    <TextBox Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,33,0,0" Name="tbItemName" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="341" />
                    <TextBlock Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,118,0,0" Name="tbServing" Text="Serving:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" />
                    <TextBox Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,96,0,0" Name="tbServingValue" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
                    <TextBlock Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,120,0,0" Name="tbUOM" Text="UOM:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" />
                    <Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="63" Margin="0,100,13,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" RenderTransformOrigin="0.455,0.286" Style="{StaticResource wp7_buttonAddNew}" x:Name="btnAddNewItem" Click="btnAddNewItem_Click"/>
                </Grid>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A User Control is another option that may be worth considering for your requirements.

Here's a walkthrough.

[Snowfall (User Control Sample)](http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone-7/tutorials/snowfall)

Answer (score 2):

Merry Christmas!

Yes, you can create a template using a DataTemplate and then very easy using this datatemplate  everywhere and whenever you want. You can have a look here: [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for some examples and full details.
Hint: When you put the DataTemplate in the resources, you can access it and use it many times.

I hope this helps. Cheers.